# NullPointerException with @Autowiered in the Main class

Tags: java, selenium

I am going to make a `@Service` which gives me a Selenium WebDriver with dependency injection. Here is the code:

```
   import java.io.File;    
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;    

    @Service
    public class WebDriverService {

        public WebDriver webDriverGetter(){
            File file = new File(SeleniumApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResource("driver/chromedriver.exe").getFile());
            String driverPath=file.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println("Webdriver is in path: "+driverPath);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",driverPath);
            WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
            return driver;
        }   

}
```

and then call the service in the main class like below:

```
public class SeleniumApplication {

    @Autowired
    static WebDriverService driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        driver.webDriverGetter().get("https://www.google.com/");        
    }
}
```

But it complains with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have set the c`hromeDriver.exe` in the path

```
src\main\resources\driver\chromedriver.exe
```

in `pom.xml` i have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: And by which magic you expect the main method to autowire anything without loading any spring context at all? You are currently having a main method. This main method accesses a variable `driver` which is null, because you never set it. There is absolutely nothing that somehow does something with your `@Autowired`, since you do not actually start Spring. You need to init Spring first, depending on which Spring you are using - or want to use, in your case.

Comment: I got some hint from your comment, but can you write an answer?

Comment: Since you do not tell us if you are using spring boot or not, it's hard to answer anything besides "start spring", which depends on what spring you are using.

Comment: Yes, i am using `Spring boot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use spring, you have to start spring somehow, which means initializing a spring context which creates your beans, etc.

In context of Spring Boot, this means, that you have your main method like this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}
```

...with `MyApplication` being a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` (often, it's the same class which contains the main method). This would start a spring boot context.

Since the main method is static, is has no access to non-static members and afaik spring does not wire static variables, you need to access it some other way, either inside a bean, for example in a `@PostConstruct` method or you get the ApplicationContext from the method above...

```
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    WebDriverService service = context.getBean(WebDriverService.class);
```

Comment: For beginning, I suggest using the Spring Initializr at https://start.spring.io/ which creates you a basic project from which you can go on. Makes it a little bit easier to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootApplication    
public class SeleniumApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

        @Autowired
        WebDriverService driver;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
             SpringApplication.run(SeleniumApplication .class, args);  
        }

        @Override
        public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
          driver.webDriverGetter().get("https://www.google.com/");      
        }

    }
```

you need to actually implement `commandLineRunner` in order to use autowired bean 
you cant do it within the main method BTW your Main class should actually have this `@SpringBootApplication` annotion.